# Issues running Firefox with Selenium over SSH

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, ssh

I have a written a Java program which uses Selenium to activate and form connections via Firefox, and am currently trying to run the program on a separate server over SSH. However, though the program works fine on my machine, when I run it over SSH I get an error. This is the specific message I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
at GoogleTestNineIndigoVersion.main(GoogleTestNineIndigoVersion.java:278)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

Build info: version: '2.42.0', revision: '5e82430', time: '2014-05-22 20:18:33'
System info: host: 'video', ip: '130.63.94.246', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.cse.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
at GoogleTestNineIndigoVersion.main(GoogleTestNineIndigoVersion.java:278)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
... 7 more
```

From the research I've done I gather that this issue comes up because, as a general rule, any given version of Selenium is only compatible with whatever were the recent versions of Firefox at the time. Most other people who have encountered similar problems have been told to upgrade Selenium. However, as I am reasonably certain I have the most recent version of Selenium (2.53.0), I assume the logical solution would be to upgrade the version of Firefox on the server I am trying to run the program on. Unfortunately, the server I am trying to run the program on is my university's server (I am creating this program as part of my summer job, working for one of my professors, and they want me to run the program on the university's server), and I obviously do not have the necessary permissions to upgrade my university's version of Firefox.

The only other solution I've been able to come up with has been to use older versions of Selenium, but this has proven fruitless. Both Selenium 2.42.0 and Selenium 2.51.0 encounter the same issue when run over SSH--the latter in particular makes me wonder if version compatibility really is the issue, considering that from what I've seen, Selenium 2.51.0 is supposed to work with the version of Firefox on the university's servers. However, I have looked at other issues people have had using Selenium over SSH and the only times I've seen the exceptions I've been getting have been for version compatibility issues.

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this issue? The version of Firefox on my laptop (which works with both Selenium 2.53.0 and 2.51.0 but encounters the same problems with 2.42.0 as the version on my university's server) is version 46.0.1, while the version on my university's server (which doesn't work with any version of Selenium I've tried) is firefox-38.6.1-1.el6.centos.x86_64 (more details included in case they are relevant).

Comment: How are the tests started?  How are you setting up the display on your university's centos server? `Error: no display specified` sounds like an issue with display setup.

Comment: you need xvfb, google "running selenium headless linux" there are plenty of instructions for any flavor of linux

Comment: I'm not running tests, but rather using Selenium to open Firefox and form connections to various webpages (I can go into more detail if need be). I'm not totally sure how to answer the second question I'm afraid -- I'm just transferring the class file over to the university's server then running the program from the command line, as opposed to running it through Eclipse as I would if I were running the program on my laptop.

Comment: Re: xvfb, I have found that as a suggestion for a similar problem someone else had, but they were getting completely different exceptions then I was, making me unsure as to whether or not that was the issue (I mostly assumed I'd run into that problem after solving the current one :P). Now that I think about it, though, I can access my program directly from one of the university's machines (though I can't run it on the specific server they want that way), so I should be able to check to see if the program works on the university's server when not run over SSH.

Comment: Ok, I've confirmed that the program indeed runs fine on the University's machines when not run over ssh, so its looking as if xvfb might be the solution after all. Hopefully. Assuming I can use it at all, which I probably can't (university's server and all that)...

Comment: Siggy, "Error: no display specified" usually means that browser is missing some display to be displayed on (real or virtual), and since you want to run via ssh, you probably don't want to attach yourself to a real display, or you may not even have one. In which case xvfb is the way to go. If that's not possible, try to configure your X11 differently. Basically try to get `firefox` to work properly inside your ssh session, If you can do that, then you probably can run selenium.

Comment: Problem has been solved. As it turns out, xvfb is already installed on the University's servers, and after some tinkering I finally found a way to get the program to run.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue in my current project, possible solution for this will find in following link https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7272

```
public  static int browserRetryCount =
                    Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("webdriver.instance.retry.count","5"));

static int browserAttempt = 1;

public WebDriver getConnection(String browserType) {

     try {

              browserDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);


     } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.logMessage("Error while initializing Driver object: "+e.getMessage());
                        String bindErrorMessage = "Unable to bind to locking port";
                        if ((e.getMessage().contains(bindErrorMessage)) && (browserAttempt<=browserRetryCount))
{
                            Logger.logMessage("Attemp2: browser instance creation!");
                            browserAttempt++;
                            int newPort = 7060+new java.util.Random().nextInt(10);
                            Logger.logMessage("newPort="+newPort);
                            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.port", newPort+"");
                            getConnection(browserType);                           
                        } else {
                            throw new UIFailure("Not able to create a driver object",e);
                        }
            }
}
```

or

you can try this also

```
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
ffBinary.setTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(180));
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, ffProfile);
```